# Найти все элементы массива, между двумя заданными значениями

Tags: c++

Код я не буду сбрасывать, так как его нет, есть только та часть, которая не поможет понять саму суть программы, но попробую объяснить на примере.

Допустим, у меня есть последовательность точек {112, 1, 30, 69, 3, 29, 74, 23, 12} и моей начальной точкой является 30, в то время как конечной является точка 23. Что мне нужно сделать, чтобы я рассматривал лишь точки {30, 69, 3, 29, 74, 23} и вывел на экран, что именно эти точки находятся между начальной и конечной точками.

Код внизу, это как мысль, которая была у меня, но я не могу докончить, так как если я начинаю с 30, как дальше сделать так, чтобы она взяла именно 69. Дистанцию не могу использовать, так как дистанция между 1 и 30 меньше чем дистанция между 30 и 69. Но я верю, что есть какая-то логика или как-то это возможно построить. Возможно моя начальная логика построена неправильно, я буду рад изменениям.

```
while(current!=end)
{
  for(points= theVectorOfPoint.begin();points!=theVectorOfPointe.end();points++)
   {

   }
}
```

Comment: Уточни. У тебя есть массив чисел, которые ты называешь точками? И тебе нужно получить (или сразу вывести?) подмассив числе между выбранными начальным и конечным значениями включительно?

Comment: Да, я представил точки и они лежат у меня в массиве

Comment: помогли ответы? Если да, то отметь пожалуйста верный или прокомментируй (а то непонятно, помогли или нет).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот мой вариант.

```
/* Отвечает за номер точки */
current = 0; 

/* Note: Для 30 можно отдельную переменную завести и для 23 */
/* В цикле находим номер точки, равной 30 */
while (points[current] != 30) { 
  current++;  
}

/* И выводим все точки с 30 по 23, найдя которую выходим из цикла */
while (current < end) { 
    cout << points[current] << " ";

    if (points[current] == 23) {
      break;
    }

    current++;
}
```

Comment: почему бы просто не сделать `break` под `if`?

Comment: ixSci дельное замечание, обновил. Спасибо.

Comment: На будущее: перед ником нужно ставить `@` — `@ixSci`, иначе уведомления пользователь не получит, если он не автор поста, к которому Вы оставляете комментарий.

Answer (score 3):

Вот немного stl-style. Правда используются возможности C++11, но можно легко обойтись без них

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main(){
    std::vector<int> v = {112, 1, 30, 69, 3, 29, 74, 23, 12};
    std::vector<int>::const_iterator first = std::find(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), 30);
    std::vector<int>::const_iterator last = std::find(first, v.cend(), 23) + 1;
    std::copy(first, last, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
}
```

Comment: Раз уж c++11, то добавьте 'auto' для итераторов